# Reading the filesystem, should it be asynchronous?

Tags: scala, file-io, playframework

From within a controller action, I want to read the filesystem.  The files will contain content, so they average file size will vary and will be I would guess a few pages of "article" type content size.

Since everything should be asynchronous, does play have a built-in method to fetch files from the filesystem that is asynchronous?

Comment: You could create an ExecutionContext that's dedicated to file io and then write a few methods that write/read files and return a future.

Comment: @SpiderPig I'd do it like that too. Create a separate execution context that meets the criteria and then implement it using Java `File` and async responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Java API's in this case. See [AsynchronousFileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html). I'm pretty sure the scalaz-stream stuff is all built on top of `java.nio` if you want idiomatic Scala.